# What is the use of the traveled distance in the Near application?

Tags: ps-vita

The Near app shows I've traveled quite a bit with my PS Vita, but what is the use of the distance traveled? Will it unlock stuff at certain distances? Is there a friends ranking?

Comment: I think some games make use of that distance traveled for certain timing events and unlocks.  I read that somewhere but I can't for the life of me remember what game it was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance counter in Near is of no use within Near, but some games reward users on how far they travelled while playing games. For example, Ecolibrium uses Near to find new creatures to unlock based on distance. You have to physically walk to a location to unlock the item.